# Add attachment based on subject of generated e-mail

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have an application which generates e-mails with invoices attached as pdf. The generated e-mails are displayed in Outlook so you can edit them manually before sending.

On all invoices I want to add an extra attachment with a kind of disclaimer. I created a macro and a button which does this. Works fine, but I want this done automaticly upon creation of the e-mail.

My questions:

- Does anyone know if it is possible to run a VBA Marco as soon as an e-mail is opened in the editor?
- I noticed there is an ItemLoad Event but when this is excecuted, no values has been assigned yet so I cannot check the subject to see if it is an e-mail with an invoice attached.

Comment: isn't there something like Mail_new? then you could check for the subject and then either add the attachment or leave it....

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow! I found it rude at the beginning myself, but one is not expected to write 'Hi' or 'Thanks'. Formatting greatly helps the reader to digest your question (or answer). Instead, be generous on upvoting other people's contributions whenever it makes sense!

Comment: Are you generating emails from a code you wrote yourself? There is an event called Read which occurs when an item is opened for editing by a user.

Answer (score 0):

In ThisOutlookSession

```
Private WithEvents InspGenSubj As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set InspGenSubj = Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub InspGenSubj_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)

    Dim curritem As Object

    Set curritem = Inspector.currentItem

    If curritem.Class = olMail Then
        If curritem.Sent = False Then
            If curritem.Subject = "Generated Mail subject" Then
                MsgBox "Code to add attachment to " & curritem.Subject
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Without knowing how the mail was generated I saved unsent mail to Drafts, closed then reopened.